# In Ruby, how do I check if at least 80% of elements in an array match a pattern?

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, matching, ruby-2.4

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I check if at least 80% of my elements in an array match a certain pattern?  I want to see if each element matches the regex

```
/\d\d?\s*-\s*\d\d?/
```

Comment: Count and do math?

Comment: Filter and compare new array with old array for percentage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#`grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) in conjunction with simple math:

```
array.grep(/\d\d?\s*-\s*\d\d?/).size / array.size.to_f >= 0.8
```

To shorten this further you can use [Numeric#`quo`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-quo) or [Numeric#`fdiv`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv):

```
array.grep(/\d\d?\s*-\s*\d\d?/).size.quo(array.size) >= 0.8
```

Comment: why not just `>= .8`   ?

Comment: You can safe the `to_f` if you write `array.grep(...).size >= 0.8 * array.size`

Comment: or `.size.fdiv(array.size) >= 0.8` or maybe even `.size.quo(array.size) >= 80/100r`

Comment: @akuhn that's true :)

Comment: @Stefan nice ones! Did not see `quo` before - TIL (thanks!)! Btw, why not `8/10r` instead of `80/100r` (I suppose intention is more clear with `80/100r`)? :)

Comment: Yeah, 80% translates literally to `80/100r`, although it's equal to `8/10r` or `4/5r`

Answer (score 1):

If performance does matter, you don't need to check all the elements to know if at least 80% of them are maching a condition

With ruby 2.3 this implementation is a bit faster than the count solution and twice faster than the grep solution :

```
def pareto_match(array, proportion: 0.8)
  min_success= (array.count * proportion).round(4)
  max_failures= (array.count * (1 - proportion)).round(4)
  success= 0
  failure= 0
  array.each do |element|
    if yield(element)
      success+= 1
      return true if success >= min_success
    else
      failure+= 1
      return false if failure > max_failures
    end
  end
end

pareto_match(array){|e| e =~ /\d\d?\s*-\s*\d\d?/}
```

Comment: Beware of floating point arithmetics. For 10 elements, `min_success` will be `8.0`, whereas `max_failures` will be `1.9999999999999996`.

Comment: Indead, I've edited the answer. I use to use Bignum for this kind of problem

Comment: Since you are counting array elements, you could just round the numbers to integers.

Comment: with `to_i` instead of `round(x)` this case is not working : `pareto_match(%w(1 2 3 a)){|e| e =~ /\d/}`

Comment: `round(x)` doesn't make much sense, because an array can't contain a fractional number of elements. I'd use `min_success = (array_count * proportion).round` and `max_failures = array.count - min_success`. You could also use `ceil` or `floor` instead of `round`.

Answer (score 0):

I would write:

```
(array.count{|item| item =~ /\d\d?\s*-\s*\d\d?/} / array.size) >= 0.8
```